# Converting JSON to CSV via CLI

Tags: json, linux, csv, command-line-interface

I am using an API to get data from NetFlow Analyzer. I get a JSON file formatted like this;

```
{"startTime":"2017-12-29 11:58","resultVector":[{"port":"*","app":"Unknown_App","dscpCode":"0","traffic":"4.77 MB","dscp":"Default","src":"20.xx.xx.2","dst":"10.xx.xx.1","dstport":"*","prot":"Unknown"}],"Type":"DestinationIN","devDetails":{"deviceID":"5000006","Total":"4.77 MB"},"TimeZone":"America/Chicago","endTime":"2018-01-05 11:58"}
```

I have been trying to use json2csv (https://github.com/jehiah/json2csv) found at github, and did have success using for a different API & JSON output format. When I run

```
json2csv -k port,app,dscpCode,traffic,dscp,src,dst,dstport,prot -i filein.json -o fileout2.csv
```

I get a csv file with nothing but ",,,,,". What I am trying to get are the traffic, source IP, and destination IP.

Running

```
json2csv -k startTime,resultVector -i filein.json -o fileout2.csv
```

gives me this output which while close, it not csv really

```
2017-12-29 11:58,[map[dscpCode:0 src:20.xx.xx.2 dst:10.xx.xx.1 prot:Unknown port:* app:Unknown_App dstport:* traffic:4.77 MB dscp:Default]]
```

Checked few online sites that report this is a valid RFC 4627 JSON. Anyone else familiar with json2csv, or if nothing else another cli tool for Linux that I can use in a script to convert?

Comment: ok, show how should look the final expected csv output

Answer (score 13):

This is a good job for **`jq`** processor:

```
jq -r '.resultVector[] | [.traffic, .src, .dst] | @csv' filein.json > fileout2.csv
```

The final `fileout2.csv` contents:

```
"4.77 MB","20.xx.xx.2","10.xx.xx.1"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly. I had tried jq but did not have the output format ".resultVector[] | [.traffic, .src, .dst]" correct, so I gave up and was trying with json2csv since I had previously luck using that. I appreciate this

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest This does not produce headers. Can/Will you offer an elegant solution that does?

Comment: @jasonleonhard, Did the OP requested preserving any headers? Had the original question any mentions about "headers"?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest fair point, however it is very common and needed in many instances.

Answer (score 0):

This is another CLI tool for conversion from JSON to CSV:

```
https://github.com/luca-vercelli/json2csv
```

It is able to parse nested JSON's.

This is the output with OP data:

```
startTime,Type,devDetails-deviceID,devDetails-Total,TimeZone,endTime,resultVector-port,resultVector-app,resultVector-dscpCode,resultVector-traffic,resultVector-dscp,resultVector-src,resultVector-dst,resultVector-dstport,resultVector-prot
2017-12-29 11:58,DestinationIN,5000006,4.77 MB,America/Chicago,2018-01-05 11:58,*,Unknown_App,0,4.77 MB,Default,20.xx.xx.2,10.xx.xx.1,*,Unknown
```

Answer (score -2):

#### Typically I prefer cli tools too

If you want to quickly format some json into csv you might also checkout this:

https://json-csv.com/

Provides file upload as well as copy pasting for quick results.